# Can a loop contain another loop in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have one main section with one `<h2>` and multiple paragraphs. I want to show a new paragraph for each `<p>`. Is there a way to have another for loop within this innercontent section so it returns new paragraphs as long as there are descriptions?

This is the HTML with liquid loops:

```
<div class="content-inner">
  {% for innercontent in page.innercontent %}
   <h2>{{ innercontent.title }}</h2>
   {% for desc in page.innercontent %}
    <p>{{ innercontent.desc }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The markdown file:

```
Section:
  - title: This is the title
    desc: This is the first description paragraph.
    desc: This is the second description paragraph.
```

Answer (score 1):

The way it is currently defined, Jekyll will just see from each section:

```
- title: This is the title
  desc: This is the second description paragraph.
```

because there are two sequences with the same name.

To define multiple descriptions for each section you can use this frontmatter:

```
---
Section:
  - title: This is the title
    desc: 
      - This is the first description paragraph.
      - This is the second description paragraph.
---
```

Then access section's frontmatter with `page.Section` and loop through all the descriptions with `innercontent.desc`:

```
<div class="content-inner">
  {% for innercontent in page.Section %}
   <h2>{{ innercontent.title }}</h2>
   {% for desc in innercontent.desc %}
    <p>{{ desc }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

That will output:

```
<div class="content-inner">

   <h2>This is the title</h2>

    <p>This is the first description paragraph.</p>

    <p>This is the second description paragraph.</p>


</div>
```